# $stmt->fetch() is not fetching the data

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I don't understand why my function is not getting the results and just getting null value. I'm using PhpStorm; all my connections are fine (Apache, MySQL, PhpMyAdmin) I've check them, also the other rest services are working.

This is my `dbhandler.php` file:

```
public function getRating($rating_id, $user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT  ur.restaurant_id, ur.service_rating, ur.food_rating, ur.music_rating FROM user_ratings ur , user u WHERE u.user_id = ? AND u.user_id = ur.user_id  AND ur.rating_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $rating_id, $user_id);


    if ($stmt->execute()) {

        $stmt->bind_result( $restaurant_id, $service_rating, $food_rating, $music_rating);
        // TODO
        //$rating_id = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->fetch();
        $res = array();
        $res["user_id"] = $user_id;
        $res["rating_id"] = $rating_id;
        $res["restaurant_id"] = $restaurant_id;
        $res["service_rating"] = $service_rating;
        $res["food_rating"] = $food_rating;
        $res["music_rating"] = $music_rating;
        $stmt->close();

        return $res;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

and this is my `index.php` file

```
$app->get('/userRatings/:rating_id', 'authenticate', function($rating_id) {
        global $user_id;
        $response = array();
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // fetch rating
        $result = $db->getRating($rating_id, $user_id);

        if ($result != NULL) {
            $response["user_id"] = $result["user_id"];
            $response["rating_id"] = $result["rating_id"];
            $response["restaurant_id"] = $result["restaurant_id"];
            $response["service_rating"] = $result["service_rating"];
            $response["food_rating"] = $result["food_rating"];
            $response["music_rating"] = $result["music_rating"];
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        } else {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
            echoRespnse(404, $response);
        }
    });
```

The response of the request is:

```
{"user_id":19,
"rating_id":"171",
"restaurant_id":null,
"service_rating":null,
"food_rating":null,
"music_rating":null}
```

Comment: Check `$stmt->num_rows` to make sure there's results.

Comment: there are data when i type my sql query to my phpMyAdmin is fetching all the data. fetchAll is not even working @Kumar

Comment: @apokryfos with num_rows() is the same result as fetch()

Comment: @Kumar `fetchAll` is PDO, OP is using `mysqli_`. Two different animals here.

Comment: @GiorgosEleftheriou it's not `num_rows()` its `num_rows` (a property), and you'll need to check that its greater than 0 otherwise it means you have no results in the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in param values. Change param values as follows.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT  ur.restaurant_id, ur.service_rating, ur.food_rating, ur.music_rating FROM user_ratings ur , user u WHERE u.user_id = ? AND u.user_id = ur.user_id  AND ur.rating_id = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("ii", $user_id,$rating_id);
```

According to your sql first param should be $user_id. Not the $rating_id.

According to your parameter settings there is no record to fetch.